# How to use cross function with numeric values in Openrefine

Tags: openrefine

I need to join 2 datasets using a common column that contains numbers (5,345,22 etc).
Is it possible to use the cross function? It appears to be functioning only with textual values, not numbers.
For ex: I would like (45,"project2","column1") to work if the number 45 is somewhere in column1 of project2.
Of course, I could convert the column to text in both project, but it it cumbersome.

Comment: Until OR 2.7, it was possible to use `cell.cross()` with two numerical columns, [even if this often caused problems](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues/1158#issuecomment-337997248). It seems that this is no longer the case, I don't know why (see my last comment in the thread).

Comment: Thank you for reporting it (and by the way, VIB Bits extension is behaving in a weird way if the column contains numeric values : the extension is trying to use a column with the right name but in an other project!)